# Computer won't boot up (only beeps)

Tags: boot, hardware-failure

My wife put my PC into sleep mode, I could not wake it up. I just got a signal on monitor saying "no signal input".

When I'm trying to boot up, I am getting two short beeps, followed by eight short beeps, then it continues to appear to load up.

I turned off the power to the PC and held the start button for 60 seconds. I also took side cover off, checked all connections, reseated ram, graphics card, also took out the battery and reset the BIOS, still nothing.

Any ideas? The PC is running Windows Vista.

Comment: POST beep codes are specific to a BIOS, but generally indicate bad things. What motherboard/BIOS or computer model?

Comment: Find out what motherboard you have and then check the Internet for beep codes.

Answer (score 1):

I going off of memory, but I believe the 2 beeps means it is post a error to the screen and the 8 beeps is video card problem. You tried re-seating and all, if you have a video card you can install confirm it is the problem that would be my next step. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

List of the computer POST / beep codes depending on the motherboard manufacturer is [here](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm) and [here](http://www.5starsupport.com/info/beep_codes.htm).

Comment: What do the link(s) say about them?

Answer (score 1):

Looking up 8 Beep's brought me to [this page](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/PC/beep.php), which listed several different Bios'. The only one that uses 8 beeps on this list is the American Megatrends Bios.

8 Beeps means you have "Display memory Read/Write test failure". 2 beeps is a "Parity circuit failure"

Based on [this page](http://www.pcguide.com/ts/x/sys/beep/amiB2-c.html), the two beeps will be diagnosed as:

> Diagnosis: This code usually means a
>   problem with either the system memory
>   or the motherboard.

and [8 beeps](http://www.pcguide.com/ts/x/sys/beep/amiB8-c.html) is fully diagnosed as:

> Diagnosis: This is usually caused by a
>   problem with the video card, or the
>   memory on the video card. It can also
>   be a motherboard issue.

The error of 8 beeps is listed as non-fatal though, so the system may start up still.

I recommend checking your cards connection to the motherboard, as well as making sure that there is no damage internally to the computer. Time to pop open your case.  You can find [troubleshooting for the Video card](http://www.pcguide.com/ts/x/comp/video/fail_Failure.htm) and then [troubleshooting the motherboard](http://www.pcguide.com/ts/x/comp/mbsys/gen_Failure.htm) as well.